# Mixing html with php search results?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to make the different the different rows have line breaks but its not working.

How is this done!? Please check my code below

Thanks guys!

James

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

{

$search = "%" . $_POST["search"] . "%";
$searchterm = "%" . $_POST["searchterm"] . "%";

}

if (!mysql_select_db("")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT name,lastname,email 
    FROM   test_mysql
    WHERE  name LIKE '$search%' AND lastname LIKE '$searchterm'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo $row["name"];
echo $row["lastname"];
echo $row["email"];
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>

<?php echo $row["name"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["lastname"];?>
<br>
<?php echo $row["email"];?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Beats me what you find so hard about it:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array(...)) {
   echo ...
   echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: sorry I haven't been using php for long. Would it be possible to put that on the code in my question so i can see exactly how its done? thanks!

Comment: Just add the `echo `<br>;` as the last line in the while() loop where you're doing the mysql_fetch_assoc call.